# python - pandas date range custom days, hours and frequency

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am trying to create a date range using `pd.date_range` from `2018-01-01` to `2018-01-31` for days of the week `Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday`, from `6 AM - 6 PM` at every `12 minutes`.

Basically, I need an array of datetime objects or strings with a value every 12 minutes for particular days of the week, between particular business hours for the given range of dates. I am not able to use `CustomBusinessDay`, `CustomBusinessHour` and `freq` together to get the desired range of datetime objects.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried creating one with the intervals you want and then filtering by meeting your day and time criteria?

Comment: @SvenH. I tried creating a range of all datetime values between the two dates at a frequency of 12 minutes, but I could not figure out how to filter out only for custom days and custom hours in an elegant fashion. But I would appreciate help in such an approach too.

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
index = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', freq='12min')
index[(index.dayofweek <= 2) & (index.hour >= 6) & (index.hour < 18)]
```